# React input box no longer works

Tags: reactjs, object, input

I am new to react and when I change my state from just variables to an object the input box no longer works.

The following code works

```
 class AddMovie extends Component {

  state = {
    title: "",
    watched: ""
  }

  onChangeMovie = (e) => {
    this.setState({[e.target.name] : e.target.value});
  }

  uploadMovie = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.addMovie(this.state.title, this.state.watched);
    this.setState({title: "", watched: ""})
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.uploadMovie}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Movie Title</label>
          <input type="text" className="form-control"  placeholder="Enter title"
          name="title" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.onChangeMovie}/>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Date Watched</label>
          <input type="date" className="form-control"
          name="watched" value={this.state.watched} onChange={this.onChangeMovie}/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default AddMovie;
```

When I change the state to an object

```
  state ={
    movieUpload: {
      title: "",
      watched: ""
    }
  }
```

and I change the form to add the object

```
  render(){
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.uploadMovie}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Movie Title</label>
          <input type="text" className="form-control"  placeholder="Enter title"
          name="title" value={this.state.movieUpload.title} onChange={this.onChangeMovie}/>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Date Watched</label>
          <input type="date" className="form-control"
          name="watched" value={this.state.movieUpload.watched} onChange={this.onChangeMovie}/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
```

The input box no longer works.  Why is this and how do I change it?

Comment: Are you changing your `onChangeMovie` method according to your new state shape?

Comment: @devserkan I have not.  What should I do to change it?

Comment: Just see my comment for the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to make those changes, you need to change your `onChangeMovie` as well

```
onChangeMovie = (e) => {
  this.setState({uploadMovie: {...this.state.uploadMovie, [e.target.name] : e.target.value}});
}
```

This will copy the current `this.state.uploadMovie` and then overwrite the title/watched.

Comment: I was giving an answer but this is a close one. I suggest using the functional `setState` here since we are depending an old value of `movieUpload`. Like: `onChangeMovie = e => {
  const { target } = e;
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    movieUpload: {
      ...prevState.movieUpload,
      [target.name]: target.value
    }
  }));
};`